# R.java file not being generated

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

i am trying to import an existing android project into my workspace. I am facing issue with R.java file. it is not getting generated. I have gone through the solutions mentioned elsewhere on this site, but nothing seems to work.
It is showing error sign on a folder drawable-xxxhdpi which has a .png file by the name ic_launcher.png in it.i cant understand what the error is.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out under `Problems` view in Eclipse(If you are using Eclipse). Should give a detailed description of the error.

Comment: Check all file names for invalid characters (such as upper case letters or spaces or - or...). If this doesn't solve it, check all your xml files for any tiny error/s. Do a Project / Clean with build automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that png file (for now). Something might be corrupted in that file.  Also, check your XML files, and ensure they are valid.

Basically sounds like something is corrupt in your resources.

Also, ensure you have tried 'Clean', then 'Build'